# Python: Quicksort with median of three

Tags: python, sorting, pivot, quicksort, median

I'm trying to change this quicksort code to work with a pivot that takes a "median of three" instead.

```
def quickSort(L, ascending = True): 
    quicksorthelp(L, 0, len(L), ascending)


def quicksorthelp(L, low, high, ascending = True): 
    result = 0
    if low < high: 
        pivot_location, result = Partition(L, low, high, ascending)  
        result += quicksorthelp(L, low, pivot_location, ascending)  
        result += quicksorthelp(L, pivot_location + 1, high, ascending)
    return result


def Partition(L, low, high, ascending = True):
    print('Quicksort, Parameter L:')
    print(L)
    result = 0 
    pivot, pidx = median_of_three(L, low, high)
    L[low], L[pidx] = L[pidx], L[low]
    i = low + 1
    for j in range(low+1, high, 1):
        result += 1
        if (ascending and L[j] < pivot) or (not ascending and L[j] > pivot):
            L[i], L[j] = L[j], L[i]  
            i += 1
    L[low], L[i-1] = L[i-1], L[low] 
    return i - 1, result

liste1 = list([3.14159, 1./127, 2.718, 1.618, -23., 3.14159])

quickSort(liste1, False)  # descending order
print('sorted:')
print(liste1)
```

But I'm not really sure how to do that. The median has to be the median of the first, middle and last element of a list. If the list has an even number of elements, middle becomes the last element of the first half.

Here's my median function:

```
def median_of_three(L, low, high):
    mid = (low+high-1)//2
    a = L[low]
    b = L[mid]
    c = L[high-1]
    if a <= b <= c:
        return b, mid
    if c <= b <= a:
        return b, mid
    if a <= c <= b:
        return c, high-1
    if b <= c <= a:
        return c, high-1
    return a, low
```

Comment: Well how would you implement the median of three as an independent function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us first implement the median-of-three for three numbers, so an independent function. We can do that by sorting the list of three elements, and then return the second element, like:

```
def median_of_three(a, b, c):
    return sorted([a, b, c])[1]
```

Now for a range `low .. high` (with `low` included, and `high` excluded), we should determine what the elements are for which we should construct the median of three:

1. the first element: `L[low]`,
2. the last element `L[high-1]`, and
3. the middle element (in case there are two such, take the first) `L[(low+high-1)//2]`.

So now we only need to patch the partitioning function to:

```
def Partition(L, low, high, ascending = True):
    print('Quicksort, Parameter L:')
    print(L)
    result = 0 
    pivot = median_of_three(L[low], L[(low+high-1)//2], L[high-1])
    i = low + 1  
    for j in range(low + 1, high, 1): 
        result += 1
        if (ascending and L[j] < pivot) or (not ascending and L[j] > pivot):
            L[i], L[j] = L[j], L[i]  
            i += 1  
    L[low], L[i-1] = L[i-1], L[low] 
    return i - 1, result
```

**EDIT**: determining the median of three elements.

The median of three elements is the element that is in the middle of the two other values. So in case `a <= b <= c`, then `b` is the median.

So we need to determine in what order the elements are, such that we can determine the element in the middle. Like:

```
def median_of_three(a, b, c):
    if a <= b and b <= c:
        return b
    if c <= b and b <= a:
        return b
    if a <= c and c <= b:
        return c
    if b <= c and c <= a:
        return c
    return a
```

So now we have defined the median of three with four `if` cases.

**EDIT2**: There is still a problem with this. After you perform a pivot, you swap the element `L[i-1]` with `L[low]` in your original code (the location of the pivot). But this of course does not work anymore: since the pivot now can be located at any of the three dimensions. Therfore we need to make the `median_of_three(..)` smarter: not only should it return the pivot element, but the location of that pivot as well:

```
def median_of_three(L, low, high):
    mid = (low+high-1)//2
    a = L[low]
    b = L[mid]
    c = L[high-1]
    if a <= b <= c:
        return b, mid
    if c <= b <= a:
        return b, mid
    if a <= c <= b:
        return c, high-1
    if b <= c <= a:
        return c, high-1
    return a, low
```

Now we can solve this problem with:

```
def Partition(L, low, high, ascending = True):
    print('Quicksort, Parameter L:')
    print(L)
    result = 0 
    pivot, pidx = median_of_three(L, low, high)
    i = low + (low == pidx)
    for j in range(low, high, 1):
        if j == pidx:
            continue
        result += 1
        if (ascending and L[j] < pivot) or (not ascending and L[j] > pivot):
            L[i], L[j] = L[j], L[i]  
            i += 1 + (i+1 == pidx)
    L[pidx], L[i-1] = L[i-1], L[pidx] 
    return i - 1, result
```

**EDIT3**: cleaning it up.

Although the above seems to work, it is quite complicated: we need to let `i` and `j` "skip" the location of the pivot.

It is probably simpler if we first move the pivot to the front of the sublist (so to the `low` index):

```
def Partition(L, low, high, ascending = True):
    print('Quicksort, Parameter L:')
    print(L)
    result = 0 
    pivot, pidx = median_of_three(L, low, high)
    L[low], L[pidx] = L[pidx], L[low]
    i = low + 1
    for j in range(low+1, high, 1):
        result += 1
        if (ascending and L[j] < pivot) or (not ascending and L[j] > pivot):
            L[i], L[j] = L[j], L[i]  
            i += 1
    L[low], L[i-1] = L[i-1], L[low] 
    return i - 1, result
```

Comment: While that works, the assignment doesn't want us to use any Python functions. So sorted() isn't an option. That's why I was hesitating with the statistics functions as well.

Comment: @Dennis: well I'm quite confident that using statistics functions are not allowed as well. But here there are basically six ways to order the elements. So I advice you to "unfold" the function yourself as an exercise.

Comment: I wrote a median function.. which is a convoluted mess but that's how I would determine the median. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Dennis: wrote a simple `median_of_three`. It is not meant to be optimal, but feel free to improve.

Comment: That actually helps a lot. Makes me realize how much shorter you can make it by using logical operators.

Comment: Why not simplify it even more writing if a <= b <= c: ? Doesn't that work in Python?

Comment: @Dennis: exactly! Chaining operators. I wanted to leave some parts as an exercise :)

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem: I'm just realizing, it doesn't sort right. With either median function. My result is: [17, 9, 3, 4, -1, 2, 1, 0] (descending) and [0, 1, -1, 3, 2, 4, 9, 17] (ascending). It worked before without the median as a pivot.

Comment: @Dennis: Well that is due to the fact that you perform a swap at the end. I did not take that into account. So you will have to update the `median_of_three`, such that it returns the index of the pviot.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. How does it return the index of the pivot? Does it get low, mid and high instead of a, b and c as parameters?

Comment: @Dennis: see edit. I however propose that you change the function where you first move the pivot element to the front of the list, since this will make things less complicated.

Comment: Alright I will need some time to understand what's going on in there now. What do I still have to change? Looks like rewriting it altogether would be the best choice at this point. Always interesting how changing one little thing (i.e. the way the pivot is determined) changes up everything.

Comment: @Dennis: well now it should probably work (well I tested it with some data). But as you can see it is rather messy. The main problem is that you want to skip the pivot (which is good), but since the pivot can now be located at three points, that becomes hard. It probably pays of to first move the pivot to the `low` (swap it with that element), and then perform the pivoting.

Comment: Tested it with several values and it works. Now I'll do my best to understand what happens and try to recreate it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I showed this to my professor and he wants me to print the indices of the swapped list elements for visualization. Problem is, when I print i and j at the end, it doesn't print the right index. What am I missing here? I added the relevant list to my original code.

Comment: @Dennis: at the end? But then the `i` and `j` are of course already changed. You thus should print the `i` and `j` immedately when a swap occurs.

Comment: Furthermore note that in the last code sample we perform additional swaps that are not related with `i` and `j`.

Comment: Van Olsem: I printed i and j right after L[i], L[j] = L[j], L[i] happens (although the result is the same whether I print a line before or after). The printed indices don't match the swapped elements. It prints (2 2) (3 5) and (5 5) but in the list, initally index 1 and 5 and at the end index 4 and 5 are swapped.

Comment: @Dennis: keep in mind that `L[low], L[pidx] = L[pidx], L[low]` and `L[low], L[i-1] = L[i-1], L[low] ` perform swaps as well. So if for example there is first a swap that swaps `(4, 3)` and then afterwards `(4 3)` again, then we already have solved the problem partially.

Comment: Oh my, what's the way to handle it then? Print all the swaps? I tried that and it's even more confusing.

Comment: @Dennis: well it is only two extra `print(..)` statements.

Comment: Oh that's not what I meant, the results look strange because it jumps from one list to a list done after 4 swaps. That's what confused me but it does work, you just have to sort it in your head. I think I'll just print out the list every time as well, at least then it's easier to follow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a "median of three" version of quicksort, you do not only want to find the median to use it as the pivot, you also want to place the maximum and the minimum values in their places so some of the pivoting is already done. In other words, you want to sort those three items in those three places. (Some variations do not want them sorted in the usual way, but I'll stick to a simpler-to-understand version for you here.)

You probably don't want to do this in a function, since function calls are fairly expensive in Python and this particular capability is not broadly useful. So you can do some code like this. Let's say the three values you want to sort are in indices `i`, `j`, and `k`, with `i < j < k`. In practice you probably would use `low`, `low + 1`, and `high`, but you can make those changes as you like.

```
if L(i) > L(j):
    L(i), L(j) = L(j), L(i)
if L(i) > L(k):
    L(i), L(k) = L(k), L(i)
if L(j) > L(k):
    L(j), L(k) = L(k), L(j)
```

There are some optimizations that can be done. For example, you probably will want to use the median value in the pivot process, so you can change the code to have stored the final value of `L(j)` in a simple variable, which reduces array lookups. Note that you cannot do this in less than three comparisons in general--you cannot reduce it to two comparisons, though in some special cases you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

one possible way can be selecting medians randomly from left and right positions.

```
def median_of_three(left, right):
    """
    Function to choose pivot point
    :param left: Left index of sub-list
    :param right: right-index of sub-list
    """

    # Pick 3 random numbers within the range of the list
    i1 = left + random.randint(0, right - left)
    i2 = left + random.randint(0, right - left)
    i3 = left + random.randint(0, right - left)

    # Return their median
    return max(min(i1, i2), min(max(i1, i2), i3))
```