# Quicksort - Median of Three with Edge Cases

Tags: python, quicksort

I am posting for help on a Quicksort median of three problem. I am required to implement a partition that uses a pivot that is the median of three elements in the input list (start, middle, end) while accounting for some edges cases.

In brief, I need to implement a method choose_median() that returns the index of the median element (the chosen pivot); print the index of the pivot chosen at the previous step; create a partition()method so that it can work with the chosen pivot; print the list after the first partition.

I've been having trouble with this case for even lists:

"Note that if the size of a list is even, there are two ways to choose a median element. To avoid ambiguity, choose an element with a smaller index as a median in this case."

This is deceptively hard, I've been stumped for a while. Especially on lists with length 2 or less.

I have a method for the partition that works for cases if given the appropriate pivot:

```
def partition(arr, pivot):
     less, equal, greater = [], [], []
     for val in arr:
          if val < pivot: less.append(val)
          if val == pivot: equal.append(val)
          if val > pivot: greater.append(val)
     return less+equal+greater, pivot
```

I could also change this function to work with the pivot too.

```
def partition(lst, pivot, start, end):
     j = start
     for i in range(start + 1, end + 1):
          if lst[i] <= lst[start]:
               j += 1
               lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]
     lst[start], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[start]
     return j
```

Choosing the median with odd number lists are straightforward.

Also, I've seen/know how to implement the implementations here:

[Python: Quicksort with median of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912873/python-quicksort-with-median-of-three)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to make this harder than it really is.  First of all, I think you confused your terminology of "median value" and "middle element".

The middle element of the list, rounding down, is simply `lst[(len(lst) - 1)//2]`: your index is the list length, minus 1, integer divide by 2.

Therefore, your pivot selection is easy: take the three indicated elements, sort them, and return the middle element.

```
def choose_pivot(lst):
    return sorted( [lst[0],
                    lst[-1],
                    lst[(len(lst)-1) //2]
                   ])[1]
```